# How to add a prefix to an operation in Zeep?

Tags: python, soap, soap-client, zeep

Need some help with a formatting issue in Zeep. Ready API shows an operation being sent with a prefix "v7" in front of the operation name. How can I reproduce this in Zeep?

Zeep output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v7="http://ads.caiso.com/api/webservices/dispatch/v7">
    <soap-env:Body>
        <getDispatchBatchesSinceUID>
            <batchUID>-1</batchUID>
        </getDispatchBatchesSinceUID>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Ready API output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v7="http://ads.caiso.com/api/webservices/dispatch/v7">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v7:getDispatchBatchesSinceUID soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <batchUID xsi:type="xsd:string">?</batchUID>
      </v7:getDispatchBatchesSinceUID>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by placing:

```
client.set_ns_prefix("v7","http://foobar/foo/bar/foo/v7")
```

To:

```
client.set_ns_prefix(None,"http://foobar/foo/bar/foo/v7")
```